# neo4j: How to get PropertyContainer from an instance of Node; using core API

Tags: neo4j

I am implementing a user defined procedure and I need to be able to get the *PropertyContainer* from a Node instance; so that I can acquire a lock.

It is not clear to me from the [documentation for *Node*](http://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/Node.html) how to do this.  The inherited methods such as [*getAllProperties()*](http://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/PropertyContainer.html#getAllProperties--) simply return a Map for the properties.

Any guidance is very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`org.neo4j.graphdb.Node` extends `org.neo4j.graphdb.PropertyContainer` (in 3.0.x) or `org.neo4j.graphdb.Entity` which itself extends `PropertyContainer` (in 3.1.x) so you don't need to do anything, just use the node instance you have.

See the javadoc you linked

> All Superinterfaces:
>   Entity, PropertyContainer

http://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/Node.html

Comment: Perfect.  This answer improved my understanding of how to use the neo4j online documentation.

Answer (score 2):

A `Node` is a `PropertyContainer` since `Node extends Entity` and `Entity extends PropertyContainer`.